# read a very large Delimited and insert data into SQL after Number of Lines

Tags: .net, vb.net

In my project, I'm reading a very large delimited file and building a StringBuilder with Insert statement.
Once the entire file is read, I'm executing the content to StringBuilder which now has a bunch of Insert statements with Data.  However, when I run execute the statement, it's timing out because of the large amount of data (about 132K or more rows).
I would like to the best way to split that into multiple chunks and execute them separately.
Initially, the original code was executing each row at a time, and that creates a lot of traffic on the database for just one process.

Each row in the text file has SQL statement like this.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.EmployeesPayrollDataImport (SSN, EID, FullName,  [Status],DepartmentCode, SSNPrior) VALUES ( ....
```

This is the code that executes the script.  But when I execute it, I get a timeout error before it finishes. I could increase the command timeout, but if the file gets larger, I would run into the same problem.  I have also tried Bulk Insert but I don't have admin permissions on the SQL server, I only have Read write permissions and I think in Bulkcopy the file has to reside on the SQL server which I don't have access to.

```
            Using Cn As New SqlConnection(sConnection)
                Cn.Open()
                Using sqlCmd As New SqlCommand(s_SQLScript.ToString, Cn)
                    sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 2000
                    rows = CInt(sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery)

                End Using 'SqlCmd
            End Using 'Cn
```

I would like to be able to execute my command in multiple chunks.

Comment: You should change what you're doing drastically. Read the file using a `TextFieldParser` and populate a `DataTable`. Once the table is full, you can use a `SqlDataAdapter` to save the data in a single batch. You would set the `SelectCommand` with a single command and parameters for each column, then save the lot with a call to `Update`. You might use `SqlBulkCopy` instead of a data adapter if appropriate.

Comment: You can also pass the datatable as parameter to a stored proc in sql server

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into either the [`SQLBulkCopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) type or the [`BULK INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) SQL command. Either of those will **give you far faster performance**, and should also help eliminate the issue in the question.

But honestly, what I tend to do is code that looks more like this:

```
Public Sub InsertEmployeePayrollDataRecords(filePath As String)
    Dim SQL As String = "INSERT INTO dbo.EmployeesPayrollDataImport (SSN, EID, FullName,  [Status],DepartmentCode, SSNPrior) VALUES (@SSN, @EID, @FullName, @Status, @DepartmentCode, @SSNPrior)"

    Dim lines = File.ReadLines(filePath).
          Skip(1). 'skip the header
          Select(Function(line) line.Split(",")) 
        ' In real code, I NEVER use string.split for this
        '  (pull a real CSV parser from NuGet instead)
        '  but I find it useful for examples on Stack Overflow
     
    Using con As New SqlConnection("connection string here"), _
          cmd As New SqlCommand(SQL, con)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SSN", SqlDbType.Char, 9)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EID", SqlDbType.Char, 14)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FullName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 60)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Status" SqlDbType.Int)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DepartmentCode", SqlDbType.Char, 5)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SSNPrior", SqlDbType.Char, 9)

        con.Open()
        For Each line() As String in lines
            cmd.Parameters("@SSN").Value = line(0)
            cmd.Parameters("@EID").Value = line(1)
            cmd.Parameters("@FullName").Value = line(2)
            cmd.Parameters("@Status").Value = line(3)
            cmd.Parameters("@DepartmentCode").Value = line(4)
            cmd.Parameters("@SSNPrior").Value = line(5)             
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Some notes on this:

- It only opens **ONE** connection to the database, which will save your system a lot of work.
- Because of the query parameters, SQL Server will see each of these as the *same query*. This will enable it to re-use the execution plan and save most of the compilation step.
- Even though SQL Server sees the same query, it will still use the correct values on each iteration
- These values are safe from any possibility of injection
- This can start executing INSERT statements as soon as the **first line** is ready, instead of needing to wait until the last line as with the original code
- This only needs enough memory to handle **one line** from the file at time, instead of the entire file
- Notice the loop itself does the minimum work possible: update existing parameter values and then execute the statement. This makes it as fast as possible using an iterative solution (`BULK` solutions are still faster)
- You don't have to mess with `CommandTimeout` anymore, because each iteration is a quick single INSERT
- I had to guess at column types. You should use actual column types from the database.

The one thing **you should NOT do** is use string concatenation or StringBuilder to include the values in your `INSERT` statements. *This is begging to have problems.* It's only a matter of time until someone puts a malicious single quote into your file and uses it to run their own queries. String concatenation/StringBuilder can still have a place in an operation like this, but *only for adding query parameter markers*. **NEVER** the values themselves.

Since you are interested in using chunks, if you wanted to you could further optimize this to have multiple copies of the same statement with a number appended to the parameter names, and an internal counter for which set of numbered parameters to use on each row and when to execute the full batch. **But I would only expect minimal performance improvement**.